# Error running previously fine code due to a new hard drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am very new to programming and python and in fact just learned how to code for this project. I wrote the code, it worked fine and months later i got a new ssd. Now i get this error **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'**

I used the code to get multiple columns as a percentage of one column. Im also getting the same error on all of my py files that use that code.

Here is the code minimum of whats causing the error and everything connected to it

```
variable = "text"

url = "linktothesite" + str.upper(variable) + "apikey"

with contextlib.closing(urllib.request.urlopen(url)) as f:
    urldata = json.loads(f.read().decode("utf-8"))

df_data = pd.DataFrame(urldata).drop(['col1', 'col2', 'col9', 'col10', 'col11'], axis=1)
df_dataAsPercentofColumn = df_data.iloc[:, 2:].div(df_data['columnname'], axis=0)
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Thank you for your time,
Rob

edit: Heres the entire traceback

```
C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/i7/PycharmProjects/fundamentalscreener/pythonProject/new test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 143, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, left, right)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 233, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 68, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/i7/PycharmProjects/fundamentalscreener/pythonProject/new test.py", line 48, in <module>
    df_balancePercentOfAssets = df_balance.iloc[:, 2:].div(df_balance['totalAssets'], axis=0)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 651, in f
    new_data = self._combine_frame(other, na_op, fill_value)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 5866, in _combine_frame
    new_data = ops.dispatch_to_series(self, other, _arith_op)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 275, in dispatch_to_series
    bm = left._mgr.operate_blockwise(right._mgr, array_op)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 364, in operate_blockwise
    return operate_blockwise(self, other, array_op)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\ops.py", line 38, in operate_blockwise
    res_values = array_op(lvals, rvals)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 190, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 150, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
  File "C:\Users\i7\PycharmProjects\fundamentalscreener\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 92, in masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Update the question to include the entire error traceback, not just the final message.

Comment: Also, I don't see how this could possibly be caused by a new hard drive...

Comment: Apparently the column structure of `df_one` changed and there is a column of strings in `df_one.iloc[:, 2:]`. We have no idea about `df_one` or the rest of the code so I doubt we can help answer your question with information you provide.

Comment: the reason i thought it was HD is because its referencing the C drive
also, updated with full traceback

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print relevant data in the except suite - is it what you expected?. There isn't enough information in your question. Please read [mre].

Comment: I added the minimal code i hope it helps. And thanks for such quick responses

Comment: It seems highly likely that, in the data you're loading and processing, some value or column that was previously either empty or contained numbers like `1` or `1.0` now contains a text, like `'1'`, `"1"`, etc.